# Como ler todos os bytes de um arquivo

Tags: c#

Estou com uma dúvida em ReadBytes(int)

Meu código é assim:

```
BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader (File.OpenRead(ARQUIVO));

byte[] arraybyte = r.ReadBytes(100000);
```

Esse `100000` que coloco é porque não sei o tamanho do arquivo, como eu posso simplesmente fazer ele ler todos os bytes do arquivo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar [`File.ReadAllBytes(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para o que pretende:

```
byte[] todosOsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ARQUIVO);
```